# Angular component not getting loaded while routing

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a `google-login` component which does google authentication for users entering my web page. After this login is successful I want to route them to `localhost:4200/books`.

When I reach `/books` it should load `search-book` component whose HTML also contains `app-book` component. If I refresh the page only then I am able to get my whole component.

So I am not able to load `app-book` component which is inside `search-book` component. But it is loaded when I refresh.

For code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arqps6

Answer (score 0):

If you have a route with an empty path and no redirect and no children, use `pathMatch: 'full'`

```
{path:'',component:GoogleLoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
```

otherwise this route will match any path.

In your case moving the `''` path below the `'books'` path would solve it as well, because then `'books'` has a chance to match.

The order of route matters, therefore more specific routes should come first.

Comment: I changed the route order, but still I require to refresh the page.

Comment: `this.router.navigate(['/books'])` (added `/`) otherwise you navigate to a child route of the current route.

Comment: I don't think relative or absolute path matter here, because only half of the search-component is getting loaded. Also I changed it but still no effect.

Comment: If you remove the filter in `<app-book-list .*ngFor="...">` this part is shown, therefore it doesn't look like the issue is with routing.

Comment: Yes. I also checked It. *ngFor data is coming from api. do u think that is the issue.

Comment: I don't know what the issue is myself. I can't properly debug. If I fork, I can't login and your stackblitz currently just throws an exception

Comment: Okay don't fork it. Just export it and it will work fine. help if possible.

Comment: I don't have TS Angular environment set up. I use only Dart myself, also exporting probably won't help. I assumed you enabled the stackblitz URL with Google auth.